# Laravel 5 Redirect problems with AJAX Get 'Class App\Http\Controllers\ does not exist'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to implement a youtube tutorial I found into my laravel php project, the tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9AF_b8wSl8)

I got the base code for the tutorial in the link that was under the video [here](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Dynamic-Photo-Gallery-JSON-Ajax-PHP-Tutorial)
I rewrote this code into a jquery php request like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#getimages").click(function(){
                var folder = 'c://xampp/htdocs/proofofconcept/savedImages/eventfolders/event1';

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getImages',
                    type: "get",
                    data: { 
                            folder: folder,
                            token: $("#_token").val()
                          },
                    dataType: "json", 
                    success: function(response){
                        var thumbnailbox = $("#thumbnailbox");
                        var pictureframe = $("#pictureframe");
                        var d = JSON.parse(response);
                        pictureframe.innerHTML = "<img src='" + d.img1.src + "'>";
                        thumbnailbox.innerHTML = "";
                        for (var o in d) {
                            if (d[o].src) {
                                thumbnailbox.innerHTML += '<div onclick="putinframe(\'' + d[o].src + '\')"><img src="' + d[o].src + '"></div>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

My html looks like this:

```
<form>
        <div id="thumbnailbox"></div>
        <div id="pictureframe"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
        <input type="button" id="getimages" name="getimages"/>
</form>
```

Now when I push the button I get a 500 internal server error (so I guess the post must be working), I am no longer getting the csrf token error which I was getting before so the problem shouldn't be there either, so the problem should be in the back end code in the method I am trying to get from so somewhere in here: 
However all of this code was working before I added the 'getImages' and 'test' functions (the test function gets the page, that one works, it's just when I try to do a get request to getImages that it fails) and all of the code that is not in getImages still works now.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Input;
use Log;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Redirect;
use DateTime;
use Response;
use URL;
use DateInterval;
use File;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class HomeController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders your application's "dashboard" for users that
    | are authenticated. Of course, you are free to change or remove the
    | controller as you wish. It is just here to get your app started!
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
        public function addArticle(){
                return view('newArticle');
        }

        public function readArticle(){
           return view('readArticle');
        }

        public function deleteArticle(){
            $articleid = Input::get('id');
            $article = DB::table('articles')->where('id',$articleid)->first();
            unlink($article->article_path);
            DB::table('articles')->where('id',$articleid)->delete();
            return Response::json(URL::route('home'), 200);
        }
        public function saveArticle(){
            $noerrors = true;
            $errors = array();
            $content = Input::get('content');
            $summary = Input::get('summary');
            $articleid = Input::get('id');
            $filepath = Input::get('filepath');
            if(!Input::has('content')){   
                $noerrors = false;
                array_push($errors,array('msg'=>"You can't upload an empty article"));
            }
            if(!Input::has('summary')){   
                $noerrors = false;
                array_push($errors,array('msg'=>"You can't upload an article without a summary"));
            }

            if($noerrors){      
                Log::info($summary . ' ' . $articleid);
                File::put($filepath,$content);
                DB::table('articles')->where('id',$articleid)->update(array(
                                                    'summary'      => $summary
                                                    )
                );            
                return Response::json(URL::route('home'), 200);
            }else{
                return Response::json($errors,500);
            }                        
        }
        public function editArticle(){
            return view('editArticle');
        }
        public function createArticle(){
            $noerrors = true;
            $errors = array();
            $content = Input::get('content');
            $summary = Input::get('summary');
            $user_id = Input::get('id');
            if(!Input::has('content')){   
                $noerrors = false;
                array_push($errors,array('msg'=>"You can't upload an empty article"));
            }
            if(!Input::has('summary')){   
                $noerrors = false;
                array_push($errors,array('msg'=>"You can't upload an article without a summary"));
            }
            $randname = str_random(42);
            $filename = $randname . '.txt';
            $filepath = '../../savedArticles/' . $filename;

            if($noerrors){      
                File::put($filepath,$content);
                DB::table('articles')->insert(array(
                                                    'poster_id'    => $user_id,
                                                    'article_path' => $filepath,
                                                    'summary'      => $summary
                                                    )
                );            
                return Response::json(URL::route('home'), 200);
            }else{
                return Response::json($errors,500);
            }            
        }
        public function getImages(){           
            /*$folder = Input::get("folder");
            $jsonData = '{';
            $dir = $folder."/";
            $dirHandle = opendir($dir); 
            $i = 0;
            while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
                    if(!is_dir($file) && strpos($file, '.jpg')){
                            $i++;
                            $src = "$dir$file";
            $jsonData .= '"img'.$i.'":{ "num":"'.$i.'","src":"'.$src.'", "name":"'.$file.'" },';
                }
            }
            closedir($dirHandle);
            $jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
            $jsonData .= '}';*/
            $jsonData = 'test';
            return $jsonData;
        }
        public function test(){
            return view('mytest');
        }
}
```

If anyone knows what might be causing the following errors or how I can work around them please let me know.
The errors I am getting are here:

```
> [2015-06-09 12:16:45] local.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException'
> with message 'Class App\Http\Controllers\ does not exist' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:776
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(776):
> ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Contro...')
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(656):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Http\Contro...', Array)
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(644):
> Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Http\Contro...', Array)
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(83):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Http\Contro...')
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(54):
> Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->makeController('App\Http\Contro...')
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(204):
> Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
> Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\Http\Contro...',
> 'HomeController')
> #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(134):
> Illuminate\Routing\Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(701):
> Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141):
> call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(101):
> call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(703):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
> #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(670):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
> Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(628):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(214):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141):
> call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(43):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(17):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> Object(Closure))
> #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(125):
> App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> Object(Closure))
> #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(55):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(125):
> Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> Object(Closure))
> #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(61):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(125):
> Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> Object(Closure))
> #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(36):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #26 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(125):
> Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> Object(Closure))
> #27 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(40):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #28 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(125):
> Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> Object(Closure))
> #29 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(42):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #30 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(125):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
> Object(Closure))
> #31 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #32 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(101):
> call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #33 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(115):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
> #34 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(84):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #35 C:\xampp\htdocs\proofofconcept\laravel\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #36 {main}
```

Comment: What does the route look like in `routes.php` that is failing?

Comment: yeah I just figured it out aswell I was going to @Homecontroller@getImages instead of Homecontroller@getImages, thanks for your time to take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearantly the problem I had was in my routing.
I had a route that was defined as:

```
Route::get('getImages','@HomeController@getImages');
```

but actually should have been:

```
Route::get('getImages','HomeController@getImages');
```